# Chutzpah console runner failing silently

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, chutzpah

Just started to get Chutzpah with require (which was great fun).

The problem I currently have now is that if there is a javascript error it seems to fail without picking any of the tests up. However, when run in debug mode it seems to pick them up in the debug.

Is there any way to solve this problem. Here is the output from my test run. There error is a " not defined" in one of the js files being tested

```
Chutzpah console test runner (64-bit .NET 4.0.30319.18033)
Copyright (C) 2013 Matthew Manela (http://matthewmanela.com).

chutzpah.dll:     Version 2.4.1.266

#_#FileStart#_# {"type":"FileStart"}
#_#FileDone#_# {"type":"FileDone","timetaken":21,"passed":0,"failed":5}

File: C:\code\origin\Test.Javascript\tests\search.test.js
     0 total, 0 failed, took 0.02 seconds

Tests complete: 0

=== 0 total, 0 failed, took 1.13 seconds ===
```

Comment: I posted a response to your same question here (https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/discussions/447424#post1058191). I have seen this happen sometimes when an certain types of errors occur. I can look further into it if you file an issue on the Chutzpah codeplex site and attach a repro of your issue.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewManela I'll reply in the forum when I can replicate it in a smaller example

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: Not at present. We haven't upgraded to the latest version yet though

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue with 0/0 tests showing.  I ran Chutzpah console with the /debug or the /openinbrowser options to get error information. It turned out I had some of the paths to JavaScript files incorrect.  Here are the [command line options](https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Command%20Line%20Options&referringTitle=Documentation).